# Extended ping on Cisco Device

Tags: python, cisco

I'm newbie in Python. I try make a script to perform automatic "extended ping".

The manual cisco flow is:

```
    switch#**ping**
    Protocol [ip]:
    Target IP address: **X.X.X.X**
    Repeat count [5]: **1000**
    Datagram size [100]: **1500**
    Timeout in seconds [2]:
    Extended commands [n]:
    Sweep range of sizes [n]:
    ####################Command Start####################
```

I try to use the command: "net_connect.send_command" from Netmiko and doesn't work.

```
    Ping_Extended = [ 'ping','\n','X.X.X.X','1000','1500','\n','\n','\n' ]

    Ping_TASA = net_connect.send_command(Ping_Extended)

    Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "VLAN1.py", line 124, in <module>
    Ping_Extended = Ping_Extended.rstrip()
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

can Someone help me?. if another method exist please shared me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: look at the message. you are trying to perform `rstrip()` on a list. [`rstrip()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html) takes a string, not a list. You must take each element in the list and apply `rstrip` to it. you should look at how to loop through that list

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that library, so I'm not sure how it works, I'm using paramiko or telnetlib, depending on the available service on the device.
My ping command on Cisco looks something like this:

```
def ping(dest, count=5, size=None, interval=None, timeout=None, source=None):
    # ignore the "interval" it's there in order to have the same signature 
    # on all devices, Cisco doesn't accept interval parameter 
    cmd = "ping %s repeat %s" % (dest, count)
    for x in [("size", size), ("timeout", timeout), ("source", source)]:
        if x[1]:
            cmd += " %s %s" % x
    cmd += " validate"
    # the "validate" seemed to be required in order to get extra statistics 
    # run the command, get the output, parse it
```

For example by calling `ping("8.8.8.8", 3, 128, 1, 2, "86.68.86.68")` will end up running `ping 8.8.8.8 repeat 3 size 128 timeout 2 source  86.68.86.68 validate` on the device.

*Side note*: instead of calling ping with no arguments and wait for the prompts, try adding "?" at end of the line (`ping ?`) in order to discover the available options, pretty much as the bash-completion works with <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I mean, from what I've seen on the devices I've worked with, you don't have to follow the flow, you should be able to execute the ping with one single command invocation.

I've taken look at the library you are using, I've noticed that the `send_command` accepts an argument `expect_string` you could use it to detect the new/different prompt, I think that your code should be something like this:

```
cmds = ['ping', 'ip', 'X.X.X.X','1000','1500','2','n','n' ]
for cmd in cmd[:-1] : 
    net_connect.send_command(cmd, expect_string='\] ?: ?')
output = net_connect.send_command(cmds[-1])
```

I've added all the defaults to the list of commands to send. If you don't want to send them, replace them with "" (empty strings).

Comment: Hello Lohmar ASHAR,

Comment: The divice is a Cisco Switch Layer 2. It just can perform ping "X.X.X.X", and not ping "X.X.X.X" repeat "XXX" size "XXX" like Layer 3 switch. The only way is make the command "ping" and press enter for more options". (Just like as I posted first). I've a SSH connection Stablished and I need to send a remote command to perform this steps to finaly print it. (I mean print command). Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know the behavior can vary between devices. I've taken a look at the library you are using and added some new idea/info that you could try.

Comment: Hello Lohmar, Thanks for your time. The error appear is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Extended.py", line 19, in <module>
    net_connect.send_command(cmd, expect_string='\] ?: ?')
  File "/home/claudio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 967, in send_command
    search_pattern))
IOError: Search pattern never detected in send_command_expect: \] ?: ?

Comment: Oh, it's the ip address line, it doesn't have a "]" in it... Change to expect_string='\]? ?: ?', the "?" after the "]" makes it optional.

Comment: Hello Lohmar, It works now but a normal ping. (be like ping X.X.X.X with normal answar "!!!!!". on each object on string "cmd" (like "ping", "ip" and so on). It's necesary apply enter to continue the next parameter. I upload a image with the entire code: (https://imageshack.com/a/img924/746/tDiUL7.png)

Comment: Hello Lohmar, I solved the issue and I posted like answer. Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue and I share with you.

```
   output = [net_connect.send_command("ping", expect_string='#?'),
             net_connect.send_command("ip", expect_string=':?'),
             net_connect.send_command("192.168.1.254", expect_string=':?'),
             net_connect.send_command("1000", expect_string=':?'),
             net_connect.send_command("1500", expect_string=':?'),
             net_connect.send_command("2", expect_string=':?'),
             net_connect.send_command("n", expect_string=':?'),
             net_connect.send_command("n", expect_string=':?', delay_factor=140)]

print output[-1]
```

Best regards